# Unity5のライトマップの設定ファイル（100MOver）のGitでの管理について。

Tags: unity3d, github

Unity5から、LightMapをbakeするとLightmapSnapshot.assetという
LightMap用のファイルが作成されるようになりました。

LightMapの設定や一次データ等が格納されているようなのですが、
ファイルサイズが100Mbを超えてしまう巨大なファイルになります。

結果として、Gitのファイルのサイズ制限にひっかかってしまう事になるため、
LightMapを使ったUnity5のプロジェクトはGitで管理できなくなってしまいました。

皆さんは現状どのように対応していますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: あれから、色々調べた結果わかったことがありますので、こちらにコメントを追加致します。

Unity5.0.0f14とUnitu5.0.0f17以降とで、Lightmapの仕様が変わっています。　今回の問題はf14以前の物だけで発生し、f17以降ではLightmapSnapshot.assetはこれほど巨大なファイルにはならないようになっていますのでGitでの管理は全く問題なくなっています。

今後　Unity5を試される方は5.0.0f17以降を試してみてください。
f17以降はリリースバージョンに近いそうです。

Answer (score 2):

Unityに限った話ではなく、`git`での巨大バイナリファイルの管理問題として回答します。（不適切でしたらごめんなさい）

`git media`という拡張があります。
これは巨大ファイル自体を管理する代わりにそのハッシュを管理して、巨大ファイル自体は別のところで格納するというものです。

但し、[リポジトリ](https://github.com/alebedev/git-media)を見ても、開発が活発だとは言いがたい状況です。。

`git`は差分管理をする都合上バイナリには弱いので、`.gitignore`で管理外とする(生成にはCIサーバなどを用意する)のが良いと考えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
拡張ができるのですね、こちらは知りませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

公式のフォーラムでもおなじ質問がありました。
細かく見ていないですが、 .gitignoreに加えてしまい再生成すればいいのではという話がでています。

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-lightmapsnapshot-asset-in-unity-5-the-same-as-unity-4s-lightprobes-asset.279969/

解決策になるかわかりませんが。

大きいファイルを履歴から消す方法はGitHubのヘルプに載っています。

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

再生成はそこそこ時間がかかってしまいますので、単体だとかまわないのですが、実際マップを何十個とつくるとなったら、再生成のタイミングは考えないといけないですね。